# Change color of outline highlight of pickable objects in VRChat

Tags: unity-game-engine

In the game VRChat whenever I create an interactable object it always gets the default blue outline highlight when hovering it.

As seen in [this tutorial video](https://youtu.be/3P3nUilBw64) when creating a pickable cube using the [VRC_Pickup](https://docs.vrchat.com/v1.0/docs/vrc_pickup), [VRC_ObjectSync](https://docs.vrchat.com/v1.0/docs/vrc_objectsync) and [VRC_SpecialLayer](https://docs.vrchat.com/v1.0/docs/vrc_speciallayer) components:

[image: Pickable cube with blue outline highlight]

I was wondering if there is a way to change the color (and maybe other effects like outline width). There's no information about this specifically that I could find. If I had to guess either the color is set in one of the [VRChat SDK](https://docs.vrchat.com/docs/setting-up-the-sdk) scripts or by Unity itself when using some API.

You can see a recent slightly modified version of the SDK online in [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/Phnky/sdk-mod/tree/master/VRCSDK/Dependencies/VRChat).

Comment: If you select the cube in the `Editor`, what is the name of the material attached to it?

Comment: This is indeed a setting inside the VRChat SDK, and is not currently modifiable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way. The outline is a part of the VRChat client itself, and so you would have to mod your client in order to get the outline to change (which is against the rules, I should add).

Theoretically, a script on all pickup-able `GameObjects` in the scene would be able to change the outline depending on how the developers created it in the first place; however, as I'm sure you know, scripts are disabled for the time being for safety reasons.